# Shouldn't the 999 call go through despite the caller losing consciousness?

Tags: plot-explanation, kingsman-the-secret-service

In [*Kingsman: The Secret Service*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingsman:_The_Secret_Service), after the bar fight, Gallahad sends an "amnesia" dart to the barman who dialed a three-digit number, which I assume is the UK emergency number 999.

The barman then fell with the phone in his hand (next to his ear, which shows he was done dialing) and Gallahad went to finish his beer.

Shouldn't the call be followed-up by emergency services anyway? I believe that like in most countries calling a number and then not hearing the caller is a signal to urgently send someone to check.

Gallahad on the other hand was not particularly in a hurry to finish the beer and the conversation.

It may have also been a quick dial number to the mob, but the effect should be the same - someone seeing the call and then silence would likely send someone to check as well.

Comment: You overestimate the resources of the emergency services. A call to 999 with no further information is not enough to really warrant an immediate response.

Comment: @Paulie_D: at least in France it does (when they can pin-point the number to an address, which is the case for a landline like in the movie)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can only speculate that the call was deemed 'not an emergency', in-universe. There is *some* rationale for that.

The UK 999 system has a structure called [Silent Solution](https://www.thamesvalley.police.uk/police-forces/thames-valley-police/areas/advice/silent-solution---999-and-55/) for callers unable to speak, whether through disability or if trying to call secretly & must remain silent. If you know the system, for instance as an abused partner etc with 'prior', then you are supposed to press 55 to indicate you are using Silent Solution. However, even without 55, the 999 operator will in any case stay on the line for some time to try extract at least some information, asking the caller to signal any kind of response - tapping, coughing, one-word answers etc - anything to identify a true response.

In the absence of **any** response, then all they can do is attempt to identify by background noise an assessment of the situation.

There would be no noise indicative of a 'dangerous' situation, merely some background conversation, and no response at all from the barman, so it's entirely possible that even in realistic terms, as opposed to simply script convenience, that no follow-up would be done.

For script convenience, of course, it was just an amusing 'nick of time' before he managed to speak to the operator, and we can forget about it once the camera cuts away.

Comment: I had another look at the scene and the barman falls down (crashing stuff) immediately. So except if the UK service answers immediately (I doubt so, there is usually, at least in France, a short moment between the call and the responder picking up), or if the calls are immediately recorded awaiting for the responder to answer - then indeed what they would have heard is silence or some chatter from Gallahad and Eggsy in the background.